# k-ary Trees in Java

Tags: java, tree

I have a non-UI use for a so-called "k-ary" tree in my Java application and was wondering if the javax.swing.tree package was the right tool for the job, even though its packaged with Swing.

I have a class of, say, Widget objects that need to be organized as a tree.  Each node of this Widget tree can have 0+ children, and thus it is not necessarily symmetric.

I need a generic Tree/Node structure that will allow me to use Widgets or any other object.  Specifically, I need a traverse that does (at the very least) post-order traversals.

If I'm not looking in the right package, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you might be able to finagle that class to do what you want, I get the sense that it's much more tightly coupled to [JTree](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) than you'd like. The general Google consensus is that building your own is a quick exercise that pays off well - I was able to find two different implementations in the top few results.

- http://vivin.net/2010/01/30/generic-n-ary-tree-in-java/
- http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2006/05/java-data-structure-generic-tree.html

If you have some burning need to roll your own, the general idea is to define a Node class with a `List<Node>` of children. Then all you have to do is provide your own methods for things like `insert`, `delete`, etc. Recursive postorder traversal is as simple as doing a regular binary postorder, except instead of left-right-root you simply walk the list of children doing postorder on each, then iterate the root last.

Comment: Hi I am trying to implement k-array tree whose output is in the form of adjacent matrix using Java. Input parameters are k=number of child for each node and d= depth of tree. given this parameter I am to generate adjacent matrix of the tree. I saw github and was not able to follow.can you please guide me to implement this?

Comment: @Learner: No, sorry, StackOverflow usually isn't for step-by-step instructions like that, and the comments *definitely* aren't the place to do it. If you're stuck on a particular part of your own implementation, feel free to ask your own question - I or someone else can help you better that way.